# Laravel 5.4 POST method not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a registration form which is sending the credentials via GET instead of POST even tho it's set to POST, that's really odd I spent hours just to figure this out also when I've changed my route I get this exception

> (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException

so here are the routes that send data through GET (no Exception):

```php
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@show');

Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

and here is the change that throws an Exception:

```php
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@show');

Route::post('/connect', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

[check the last 2 commits for more](https://github.com/Maydara86/Laravel-5.4-tutorial/commits/ep19_broken)

Comment: It is `method`, not `methode`, that is why your request is GET and not POST.

Comment: OMG :(  this is so stupid

Answer (score 2):

You use `methode` instead of `method` (without e) in your form.